# Integral operator doesn't attend norm of kernel in $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: hilbert-spaces

$H=L^2[0,1]$, $K \in L^2([0,1]\times[0,1]) $, $f \in L^2[0,1]$ . If I have $J: H \to H$ given by
$$
(Jf)(s) \overset{a.e}{=} \int_0^1 K(s,t) f(t)dt
$$
In what case $\| J \|_{\text{op}}< \| K \|_2$ ? Can you give an example?

Thanks

Comment: I guess if J is self-adjoint then it won't happen

Comment: This MIT lecture video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78vN4sO7FVU&list=PLUl4u3cNGP63micsJp_--fRAjZXPrQzW_&index=2) claims (without proof) that this inequality is *always* strict under the infinity norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to see that in general $\|J\| \leq \| K \|_2$.

Here's an example in which the norm of $K$ is not attained. Define 
$$
K(s,t):= \chi_{[0,s]}(t)
$$
Then, 
$$
\| K \|_2^2=\int_0^1 \int_{0}^1 |\chi_{[0,s]}(t)|^2 dt ds = \int_0^1 s ds = \frac{1}{2} 
$$
Thus, $\| K \|_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Now, notice that in this case
$$
(Jf)(s)=\int_0^s f(t) dt
$$
You can check (with some work though) that $\| J \|=\frac{2}{\pi} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\| K \|_2$.